# How can I render something only once in react? (more below)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, while-loop, react-hooks

I'm making a **battleship game** to learn react. I generate and randomly place 5 ships on the board, and if 2 ships share the same grids, I want to re-generate end re-place every ship. I tried while loops mainly, but most of the time I got an infinite loop, or something unexpected. I suppose the problem is I don't know how to control when the component should re-render.

This is my code (I removed the unneccesary parts):

```
const GameControl = () => {
    const [playerBoard, setPlayerBoard] = useState(() => GameBoard('player'));
    const [playerShipsArray, setPlayerShipsArray] = useState([]);


    //setting up game
    useEffect(() => {
        generateShips()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {

           // while(!checkTakenCells(playerShipsArray)){
           //     generateShips()
           // } **this is the problematic part**

    }, [playerShipsArray])

    placeShipsOnBoard(playerShipsArray, playerBoard)
    //setting up game

    function generateShips() {
        let shipsArr = [];
        while(shipsArr.length < 5){
            for(let i = 1; i < 6; i++){
                let startCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

                const ship = Ship(i, i, isVertical(), startCoord)

                shipsArr.push(ship)
            }
        setPlayerShipsArray(shipsArr)
        }


    function checkTakenCells (array){
        let takenCells = [];
        array.forEach(ship => takenCells.push(...ship.takenCells()))
        //if 2 ships share the same coordinate, the takenCells array will have the shared coordinate twice
            return new Set(takenCells).size === takenCells.length //If ships are colliding, returns false
    }
    

    function placeShipsOnBoard(array, board){
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            board.placeShip(array[i], array[i].startCoord) 
        }
    }  
  
        return (
            <>
              //looping through playerBoard to generate a 10x10 grid
            </>
        )
}
```

Comment: You could check the length of playerShipsArray to see if you've already run generateShips. In my code, I've occasionaly set a line `const [mounted, mount] = useState(false)` that I switch to true when all the start up processes of the component are complete. If you need to always remember when your code has processed something, even if the component that did it has been destroyed you'll probably want some kind of global state library.

Answer (score 0):

```
const GameControl = () => {
    const [playerBoard, setPlayerBoard] = useState(() => GameBoard('player'));
    const [playerShipsArray, setPlayerShipsArray] = useState([]);

    //setting up game
    useEffect(() => { generateShips() }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
           // while(!checkTakenCells(playerShipsArray)){
           //     generateShips()
           // } **this is the problematic part**

    }, [playerShipsArray])

    placeShipsOnBoard(playerShipsArray, playerBoard)
 }
```

You code using `hooks` are fine, but keep in mind, everything inside `GameControl` will be re-run whenever a state changes.

Which means `placeShipsOnBoard` will be called again and again :)

This might be some boilercode, keep in mind React component isn't a game machine, it won't run every milli-second. It'll only run when something changed.

```
  const GameControl = () => {
    const [ships, setShips] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // for every 50ms, 
        // move. the location of ships
        setShips(newLocationShips)
      }, 50)
    }, [])

    // render ships to the board
    return (ships.map(ship => ())
```

You need to think of a board which is not changing, and then ships which is changing based on something, which could be event or time.